# Can HTML tags contain new lines within the tag between attributes?

Tags: html

Can I use enter or line break to separate HTML attributes within an HTML tag?

For example:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="usrnm"
    placeholder="Username"
/>
```

Comment: Next time, you could just do it and see what happens. If it works, you could test it in a html validator to check if it's valid.

Comment: I don't have no laptop with me when I wrote this, and I was in hurry.
I'll try to be careful next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not completely conventional (in terms of [industry standards for the markup language](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)), it will function. Just put your example into a `.html` file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Page
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <input
        type = "text"
        name="usrnm"
        placeholder="Username"
    />
</body>
</html>
```

You'll notice that this does render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is perfectly functional. Extra spaces, tabs and newlines don't really affect HTML, but it will almost always annoy the hell out of your coworkers. Don't do that.

Comment: I'll use newlines when I work alone. Thanks for the tips.